# How to build an array of HTML elements and their attributes in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to build an array of array in jquery to store data and use them later in my code.
I'm looking to have something like this:

```
array[html_node][attribute] = attribute value
```

based on this type of DOM:

```
<div id= node>
  <a step= "downloading" data="123">
    ...
  </a>
  <a step= "waiting" data="122">
    ...
  </a>
</div>
```

can you help me figure this out?

Comment: Are you trying to store every single node from the DOM in an array? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What are you going to do with this? jQuery already can search and collect attribute data across the DOM for you. Even plain ol' js can do quite a bit of that with the `getElement...` functions.

Comment: you've already got the DOM. why duplicate it?

Comment: Can you show us what you would like your array values to look like? ie `array[a][data] = 123`? or `array[downloading][data] = 123`?

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the previous comments *(why create an array of stored data when the DOM is a perfectly good substitute?)*, here is something along-the-lines of what I believe you're after:

```
var arr = [];

$('#node a').each(function(){

  arr.push( $(this).attr('data') );

});
```

Or perhaps you are wanting the `node` as a class, where there will be multiple `nodes`:

```
var arr = [];

$('.node').each(function(i){

  arr.push([]);

  $(this).children('a').each(function(){

    arr[i].push( $(this).attr('data') );

  });
});
```

Or if you are wanting to store a reference to the node (which is difficult using just arrays as you'll need a *key* in there somewhere):

```
var arr = [];

$('.node').each(function(i){

  arr.push({ node:this, data:[] });

  $(this).children('a').each(function(){

    arr[i].data.push( $(this).attr('data') );

  });
});
```

[*Here's a fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/PjW52/) (with references to the id of the node so-as not to choke the `JSON.stringify` part.

Comment: NB: this is just an array of the data - there's no reference to which element actually held that data.

Comment: @Alnitak Very true, but the OP never said he wanted to reference the element; he only said he wanted to use later the *data from the element*. (I know, perhaps the OP expressed itself wrong, but so far this answer the question)

Comment: @chris-l I disagree - the OP clearly shows (albeit incorrectly) the intent to maintain a 2D array of element and attribute.

Comment: Would stringify be useful in this instance?

Comment: @PseudoNym01 Unfortunately not because the node-referencing would probably send it loopy

Comment: hmm, I think I could see that. JS isn't my strong suit, for my own curiosity could you elaborate more?

Comment: @PseudoNym01 Well the problem largely stems from the question of how to encapsulate a DOM node? A DOM node loses its usefulness when referencing it from outside of the context of the document. Which is often what JSON.stringify is used for: transporting objects from one environment to another in a uniform way.

Answer (score 0):

One of the hidden gems in Javascript which I think fades most people are the use of data structures. In particular the use of **structs**

For what you are trying to do, it is virtually impossible to have the layout like you want it

> array[html_node][attribute] = attribute value

The reason being, you would have to assign numbers to your `html_node`'s so you would either have to hardcode those in, in order to access them the way you want to, or create some complicated algorithm to retrieve the value of that specific node.

Another issue I am seeing here, is that there can be duplicate html nodes. Meaning, you can have multiple `html_node` values of `'DIV'` but they have different attribute data. In any event, there can be only one object in the array for `array[DIV]` so there will also need to be some sort of way to distinguish between each node.

---

Your solution :

### Javascript Structs

These have the ability to be super flexible as well as easily accessible.

***First*** - You will need to make a `struct factory` to initialize everything. **Don't worry if you don't completely understand the factory**, all you need to do is copy and paste the Javascript code. *(However, it is additionally helpful if you can grasp the concept)*

```
function makeStruct(names) {
  var names = names.split(' ');
  var count = names.length;
  function constructor() {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      this[names[i]] = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  return constructor;
}
```

***Second*** - Create your struct and initialize array

```
var HTML_Node = makeStruct("node step data");
var array = [];
```

***Third*** - Add elements to your struct

```
$('#node').children().each(function(){
    array.push(new HTML_Node(this.nodeName, $(this).attr('step'), $(this).attr('data')));
});
```

***Fourth*** - Get elements from your struct, which is real simple with a loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
//All of these if statements will be referencing node / step / data as set up in step 2

    if(array[i].node == 'DIV'){
        //if the node is a DIV element do something
    }

    if(array[i].step == 'waiting'){
        //if the node's step is waiting do something
    }

    if(array[i].data == '123'){
        //if the node's data is 123 do something
    }
}
```

And that is how you can use structs to create a simple data structure to store all of the information needed.

Comment: nothing wrong with this, but I wouldn't go and overrride the globally available [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node) object...

Comment: @shennan good point, was just doing it for clarity, but I'll change it up. Thanks for pointing it out.